# Append HTML Element from Object Property

Tags: javascript, html, javascript-objects

I'm working on my little code.
I want to append some HTML element from my array object.
These are my codes.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  <div class="container">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**Javascript**

```
var obj=[
  {
    name: "john",
    phone: "0831",
    tasks:["run","slide"]
  },
  {
    name: "billy",
    phone: "0798",
    tasks: ["swim", "fly", "crawl"]
  }
]

var str="";

for(i=0;i<obj.length;i++){
    str+='<div>';
    str+='<h1>'+obj[i].name+'</h1>';
    str+='<p>'+obj[i].phone+'</p>';
    str+='<ul>'
    str+='<li>'+obj[i].tasks[0]+'</li>';
    str+='<li>'+obj[i].tasks[1]+'</li>';
    str+='<li>'+obj[i].tasks[2]+'</li>';
    str+='</ul>'
    str+='</div>';

    $(".container").html(str);
}
```

**Problem**

The problem is when i want to append **tasks** object property on multiple **li** element, there's one undefined property because of the different between property amount.

**Recent Output**

```
<div class="container">
  <div>
    <h1>john</h1>
    <p>0831</p>
    <ul>
      <li>run</li>
      <li>slide</li>
      <li>undefined</li>
    </ul></div>
  <div>
    <h1>billy</h1>
    <p>0798</p>
    <ul>
      <li>swim</li>
      <li>fly</li>
      <li>crawl</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Question**

My question is how to append li element to be the same amount as object property, so there's no more undefined property like i mention above?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe like this

```
...
str+='<ul>'
for (var ii = 0; ii < obj[i].tasks.length; ii++) {
    str+='<li>'+obj[i].tasks[ii]+'</li>';
}
str+='</ul>'
...
```